# A leap year determining C program is not giving any output when inputting 2000, 1900 or 2100 as an input

Tags: c, if-statement, nested-if, leap-year, relational-operators

When I am running this C program, and giving 2020, 2024 or other years perfectly divisible by 4, then I am getting expected output i.e. it is a leap year.
**But when I am giving a century year : 1900, 2000 or 2100 etc. as an input, then it's not not giving me any output.**

> Please do not suggest me the correct program as there are many
> available on internet and I understood them already. You are requested
> to tell me why my program is not giving any output when entering a
> century year.

*P.S. this program gives no error.*

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter year : "); scanf("%d",&n);
    
    if (n%4==0)
    {
        if(n%100 != 0)
        {
            printf("Leap year"); 
        }
    }
    else if(n%100 == 0)
    {
        if (n%400==0)
        {
            //`enter code here`
            printf("Leap year");
        }
    }
    else 
        printf("Not a Leap year");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(n%100 == 0)` is never true because you only evaluate this when `n%4 != 0`.

Comment: Please indent your code well, this helps understanding the conditions under which a code path will or will not be reached.

Comment: _"P.S. this program gives no error."_ Try entering something other than a number.

Comment: @Zakk: That's s a different thing altogether -- the ubiquitous "using `scanf()` without checking the return value". Which does not lead to an error message necessarily, but to undefined behaviour (access of uninitialized value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in this part of the code:

```
if (n%4==0)
{
    if(n%100 != 0)
    {
        printf("Leap year"); 
    }
}
```

When you enter 1900, it enters the first condition. (Because 1900%4 is equal to zero.) And then, it checks whether or not 1900%100 is zero, and as you can see, it is zero, so it doesn't enter the if(n%100!=0) condition, and there is no other else statement in the if (n%4==0). So there is no condition for the code to enter. And therefore it doesn't give any output.
Plus your code never enters `else if(n%100 == 0)` part because any number that is divisible by 100 is also divisible by 4.

Answer (score 0):

This if statement

```
    if (n%4==0)
{
    if(n%100 != 0)
    {
        printf("Leap year"); 
    }
}
```

gets the control for years like 1900 because they are divisible by 4. But as such a year is also divisible by 100 then nothing is outputted.

So your program has a logical error.

You could rewrite the if statements for example the following way

```
if ( ( n % 4 != 0 ) || ( n % 100 == 0 && n % 400 != 0 ) )
{
    printf("Not a Leap year");
}
else
{ 
    printf("Leap year"); 
}
```

or

```
if ( ( n % 4 == 0 ) && ( n % 400 == 0 || n % 100 != 0 ) )
{
    printf("Leap year"); 
}
else
{ 
    printf("Not a Leap year");
}
```

Or if to use nested if-else statements then the code can look like

```
if ( n % 4 == 0 )
{
    if ( n % 400 == 0 )
    {
        printf("Leap year"); 
    }
    else if ( n % 100 != 0 )
    {
        printf("Leap year"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not a Leap year");
    }
}
else
{ 
    printf("Not a Leap year");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic has the following structure:

```
if ( n % 4 == 0 )
{
    if ( n % 100 != 0 )
    {
        printf( "Leap year\n" ); 
    }
}

else if ( n % 100 == 0 )
{
    if ( n % 400 == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Leap year\n" );
    }
}

else
{
    printf( "Not a Leap year\n" );
}
```

Instead of writing `else if`, I will add braces `{` `}` to every `else` statement, to make it clear what the `else` is actually referring to. Adding the braces does not change the behavior of your program.

```
if ( n % 4 == 0 )
{
    if ( n % 100 != 0 )
    {
        printf( "Leap year\n" ); 
    }
}
else
{
    if ( n % 100 == 0 )
    {
        if ( n % 400 == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Leap year\n" );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Not a Leap year\n" );
    }
}
```

Now you can clearly see that if the `if` condition `n % 4 == 0` is true, then the first outer block will be executed, otherwise the second outer block will be executed.

However, this logic is wrong. If the condition `n % 4 == 0` is true, then the first outer block will be executed, which means that your program will print `"Leap year"` if the `if` condition `n % 100 != 0` is true, but will do nothing (i.e. print nothing) if that `if` condition is false. This is not what you want.

What you want is rather the following logic:

```
if ( n % 4 != 0 )
{
    printf( "Not a Leap year\n" );
}
else
{
    if ( n % 100 != 0 )
    {
        printf( "Leap year\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        if ( n % 400 != 0 )
        {
            printf( "Not a Leap year\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Leap year\n" );
        }
    }
}
```

This can be more compactly written by removing all braces:

```
if ( n % 4 != 0 )
    printf( "Not a Leap year\n" );

else if ( n % 100 != 0 )
    printf( "Leap year\n" );

else if ( n % 400 != 0 )
    printf( "Not a Leap year\n" );

else
    printf( "Leap year\n" );
```